# Issues with upgrading iPhone4 to iOS 6

Tags: mac, itunes, upgrade, iphone, ios

When I last upgrade my iPhone 4 to iOS 5, I later had to install another version of iTunes on my macbook to synchronize my files between my computer and my iPhone. This new version of iTunes required a new version of Quick Time, which took me a long time to find available on the internet.

Now my iPhone says that I need to upgrade to iOS 6. My macbook runs on Mac OS X leopard (10.5.8), which only supports java 1.5.

Which issues should I be aware of when upgrading to iOS 6, given my macbook's limitations?

Comment: Which version of iTunes do you have?

Comment: iTunes 10.6.1 .

Comment: Can you upgrade to iTunes 10.7? That is required for iOS 6. That said, you should probably upgrade from OS X 10.5 if possible.

Comment: I ran Software Update and could only update to iTunes 10.6.3. If I upgrade to OS X 10.6, which is snow leopard already I think, I'll probably need a new macbook. Thanks for your help, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS needs iTunes 10.7 which in turn needs OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard. The other workaround you can do is do an on-the-air update for your iPhone from iOS 5 to iOS 6 but then you won't be able to sync your iPhone with your Mac.

Hope that helps.